# How to install MapLibre-gl in React Native CLI

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli, maptiler, maplibre-gl

I am trying to install MapLibre-gl in react native CLI but I can't find any useful documentation or any step-by-step guide, all I found was some complex stuff that leads to many errors.

I need some explanation on how to install it since there is no npm for it.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here are a couple of resources that I found that might be useful:

[How to use MapLibre GL Js in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67952068/how-to-use-maplibre-gl-js-in-react-native)
https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/get-started/get-started
https://docs.maptiler.com/maplibre-gl-js/
https://documentation.maptiler.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405444890897-How-to-display-MapLibre-GL-JS-map-using-React-JS

In case you would like to ask for further help, find me at support@maptiler.com

Jiri